# Getting this error while running the navigation drawer activity

Tags: android

> error is:
>
> 07/18 11:08:26: Launching app $ adb install-multiple -r -t
>   E:\Nav_drawer\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_2.apk
>   E:\Nav_drawer\app\build\intermediates\instant-run-apk\debug\app-debug.apk
>   E:\Nav_drawer\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_1.apk
>   E:\Nav_drawer\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_8.apk
>   E:\Nav_drawer\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_5.apk
>   E:\Nav_drawer\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_6.apk
>   E:\Nav_drawer\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_7.apk
>   E:\Nav_drawer\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_4.apk
>   E:\Nav_drawer\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_9.apk
>   E:\Nav_drawer\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_3.apk
>   E:\Nav_drawer\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\dep\dependencies.apk
>   E:\Nav_drawer\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_0.apk
>   Split APKs installed $ adb shell am start -n
>   "com.example.nidhi.nav_drawer/com.example.nidhi.nav_drawer.MainActivity"
>   -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER Client not ready yet..Waiting for process to come online Waiting for
>   process to come online Connected to process 3012 on device
>   emulator-5554 Capturing and displaying logcat messages from
>   application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output"
>   section of the "Debugger" settings page. D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting
>   down VM

```
              --------- beginning of crash
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.nidhi.nav_drawer, PID: 3012
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.nidhi.nav_drawer/com.example.nidhi.nav_drawer.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.FrameLayout cannot be cast to android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
                   Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.FrameLayout cannot be cast to android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                      at com.example.nidhi.nav_drawer.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:32)
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776) 
Application terminated.
```

Answer (score 0):

your code says that FramLayout can not cast to toolbar

so that means you casting Framelayout to Toolbar like this

```
frame = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.Frameloayout);
```

try changing like this

```
frame = (Framelayout) findViewById(R.id.Frameloayout);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to cast FrameLayout to Toolbar..? FrameLayout never cast to Toolbar please change it.